# SQL Select rows having count > 1 and a row not exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to write an sql in MS Access where:

I have a table having columns(id,Name,code)

I need to select all the records which have same Name occuring more than once where there does not exist among the rows a row where code IS NULL

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
SELECT Name
FROM   TableName
GROUP  BY Name
HAVING NOT EXISTS ( Select Name FROM TableName Where code IS NULL Group By Name Having COUNT(*) > 1) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   Name
FROM     TableName
GROUP BY Name
HAVING   sum(IIF(code is null OR code = 0, 1, 0)) = 0
   AND   COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Access does not accept this query. It gives a syntax error.

Comment: Yes now there is no syntax error ! Can I add (OR code = 0) ? It seems not all rows appear when I add it

Comment: You could change `IIF(code is null OR code = 0, 1, 0)` to `IIF(NZ(Code,0)=0,1,0)`.